# Float a DIV in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following URL: [Website](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/Portal/test.php?zh=loadPage)

What I am looking to do really is float the Weather DIV on top of the page just like it is now, but when i expand or collapse it, it just floats on top and does not push any of the contents down. How do I achieve it?

My weather DIV CSS:

```
#weather {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 177px;
    font: 75%/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999999;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position it absolutely

```
#weather {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 177px;
    margin-left: -88px; /* 50% of the width */
}
```

and give your body a `padding-top` in the height of your current wrapper

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px; /* or so */
}
```

Comment: Will also need to add left: 50%;

Comment: Did the trick, Thanks. I would like it centered between the logo and the welcome sign....

Comment: @Linus Caldwell, Where should I put the WEATHER div? Inside which DIV?

Comment: @SiKni8, leave it directly inside your body. Does not matter where (currently).

Answer (score 1):

You can give a relative or absolute position to it.

Comment: #weather {position: relative; top:0px;}

Answer (score 1):

It might be best to place your '#weather' element inside of your '#wrapper .shell' area of the dom and give it an 'position: absolute' property.

'position: absolute' basically tells the browser to ignore the element's height and instead hands all display responsibility off to the css that you define for it.

Also, You can make it look a lot nicer by setting the '#weather' width to 990px (The width of your site's frame). This will extend the black bar across the width of your site's frame as well. This will begin to clean things up for you.

Comment: I did what you said but now it's not centered anymore :(

Comment: You set the #weather's width to 990px as well?

Comment: @SiKni8, in that case you need `.shell { position: relative; }`.

Comment: One issue I am having is centering the "sd" div inside the "panel" div. please help

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` with a fixed `width`.